# Sending a javascript function from the client to the server to format the response received from the database and return a csv to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, client-server

I have a use case where i need to generate csv reports for the bunch of queries.

I have a common `POST` reqHandler on the backend written in nodejs/express which receives a json object as follows

```
{
    "converter": <converter function>,
    "fields": <CSV header fields >,
    "reqUrl": <REST API>,
    "queryObj": <queryObject for the API>
}
```

On the backend I am `eval()`ing on the converter function and execute the function on the response object from the REST API, format the response and returning an attachment using `res.download` to the client.

What are the security implications on this? Is there any other approach to this problem?

PS: This endpoint is accessible only for a specific set of users (Admin for eg)

Comment: You have an endpoint that `eval()` strings? Interesting... Imagine your worst enemy has bad intentions, what could he do?

Comment: Ahhhh. Thanks. Just trying to find out possible security flaws on this front. Here is a good explanation of possible risks of doing so.

http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

First off evaluating a code that came directly from a post request is a very bad practice security wise, you would have your application exposed on a serious security threat as users may send any javascript function to your application. Even though this post url is only accessible to administrators, you would still want to filter the amount of javascript they can execute. I would suggest you create an object that contains the functions you need and then from the post request just send the name or alias of that function. This way you are limiting the access of users and the threats your system would be exposed to.

In my experience, even though a system is only available to our operations department it is still subject to a lot of security issues that are caused by "Accidents" as they say.